# async not working on pressing back key of Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

```
private async void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    var msg = new MessageDialog("Confirm Close");
    var okBtn = new UICommand("OK");
    var cancelBtn = new UICommand("Cancel");
    msg.Commands.Add(okBtn);
    msg.Commands.Add(cancelBtn);
    IUICommand result = await msg.ShowAsync();
}
```

the main problem is when back button is pressed the message is shown for 1-2 sec and the app closes.
What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async is working fine I think, you are not setting *e.Handeled* to *true*, which means that further BackPressed events are processed and app exits. Try like this:

```cs
private async void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    var msg = new MessageDialog("Confirm Close");
    var okBtn = new UICommand("OK");
    var cancelBtn = new UICommand("Cancel");
    msg.Commands.Add(okBtn);
    msg.Commands.Add(cancelBtn);
    IUICommand result = await msg.ShowAsync();
}
```

Remember also that your app must be able to exit via BackButton, so the code above has to be somehow modified.

Comment: Thank You it was because of the e.handled

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var messgeDialog = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to close", "Are you sure?");
                    messgeDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes"));
                    messgeDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No"));
                    messgeDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
                    messgeDialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
                    var result = await messgeDialog.ShowAsync();
                    if (result.Label.Equals("Yes"))
                    {
                    //Do something when a user pressed yes
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    //User pressed no
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you The if else of label helped to close the application :)

Comment: @shriyanshk you can also do this: else if(result.Label.Equals("Help"){//do something here} but you also have to create the Help command to do this add this line: messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Help"));